# attribute errors: module has no attribute in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I am trying to run a sample script where I use

```
import tensorflow as tf
def main():
  if __name__ = '__main__':
  tf.app.run(main = main)
```

that throws an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
```

but when i run it as:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import app
```

it runs well.. the python version I am using is 3.6.1 and tensorflow version: 0.1.8

actuall even

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

is showing an attribute error..

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: what is the output of print( dir(tf))?

Comment: This is the outpt: ['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'core', 'python']

Comment: these are not attributes of tensorflow. You may have  file called tensorflow.py in working directory. please check that

Comment: dir /s *tensorflow.py*
 
     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)            all of them named: pywrap_tensorflow.py

Comment: can you change your working directory and try from there?

Comment: I had a tensorflow serving library in my cwd.. and when i removed it i get: ['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__'] when i run print(dir(tf))

Comment: I am using a conda virtual environment.. and tensorflow is installed only in the single virtual environment that I am using.. yes I have activated the virtual environment..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157433/discussion-between-mitiku-and-thealchemist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mitiku pointed out.. there was a problem with the installation so i reinstalled it.. and it works now..

print( dir(tf)) -- this should show the list of packages under tensorflow..

Comment: Just to make it clear `dir` shows all the attributes an object has, in this case the object was a module(of tensorflow's package), and it showed all the attributes this module has .

Answer (score 0):

My problem was running Tensorflow 1 script for version 2.

tf.app is moved to tf.compat.v1.app in version 2. There is a tool that helps to upgrade to version 2 automatically.

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --intree my_project/ --outtree my_project_v2/ --reportfile report.txt
```

I put it here in case somebody had same issue.